# problemas al mostrar datos con livewire

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Tengo un área de reportes para la cual estoy usando livewire, necesito que los reportes se puedan filtrar por categoría del artículo, esto me funciona mientras no se seleccione la opción de 'todos' que tengo dentro de un select:

```
       <span>Seleccionar categoría</span>
            <div class="form-group">
               <select class="form-control" wire:model="categoriaId" name="categoria" id="categoriaId">
                       <option value="">Seleccionar categoría</option>
                       <option value="0">Todas</option>
                       @foreach ($categorias as $categoria)
                          <option value="{{ $categoria->id }}">{{ $categoria->nombre }}</option>
                       @endforeach
               </select>
            </div>
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para mostrar todas las categorías al seleccionar esa opción en mi tabla para el reporte?

Aquí está la parte de mi controlador:

```
public function Articulos()
{
    //dd($this);

if ($this->artcero == 'si') {
    $this->data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
    ->when($this->categoriaId !== 0, function($query) {
        return $query->where('categoria_id', $this->categoriaId)
        ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom');
    })
    ->when($this->categoriaId == null, function($query) {
        return $query->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom');
    })
    ->get();        
    return $this->data;

} elseif ($this->artcero == 'no') {
    $this->data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
    ->when($this->categoriaId !== 0, function($query) {
        return $query->where('categoria_id', $this->categoriaId)
        ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom');
    })
    ->when($this->categoriaId == null, function($query) {
        return $query->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom');
    })
    ->where('stock', '>', 0)
    ->get();
    return $this->data;
}
```

Y donde defino las variables:

```
public $nombreComponente, $data, $categoriaId, $alm;
public function mount()
{
    $this->nombreComponente = 'Reportes';
    $this->data = [];
    $this->artcero = 'si';
    $this->alm = [];
}

public function render()
{
    $this->Articulos();
    return view('livewire.articuloreports.articulocomponent', [
        'articulos' => Articulo::get(),
        'almacenes' => Almacen::get(),
        'categorias' => Categoria::get()
    ])->extends('adminlte::page')
        ->section('content');
}
```

la `categoriaId` por alguna razón me la está tomando nula al seleccionar 'todos'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo logré arreglar al filtrar primero por categoría, de la siguiente forma:

```
if ($this->categoriaId == null) {
    $this->data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
    ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom')
    ->whereHas('detallearticulos', function($q) {

        $q->whereIn('almacen_id', $this->selectedAlm);
    
    })
    ->when($this->artcero == 'no', function($query){
        return $query->where('stock', '>', 0);
    })
    ->OrderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->get();
} elseif ($this->categoriaId !== null) {
    $this->data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
    ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom')
    ->whereHas('detallearticulos', function($q) {

        $q->whereIn('almacen_id', $this->selectedAlm);
    
    })->with('detallearticulos')
    ->when($this->artcero == 'no', function($query){
        return $query->where('stock', '>', 0);
    })
    ->where('categoria_id', $this->categoriaId)
    ->OrderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Ahora sí realiza todas las funciones que quería.